# How to read multiple properties in Spring Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, resourcebundle

I have two properties file in my application-

```
app.properties
level.user=username
easyDeploy_general.properties
user.update=Update
```

I have defined them in `spring-servlet.xml` in below way

```xml
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>WEB-INF/resources/easyDeploy_general</value>
            <value>WEB-INF/resources/app</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now,I want to access those property key value pair from my controller. How can I achieve these?

Comment: hwo is your controller defined? is it annotated?

Answer (score 2):

If your controller is annotated then you can use [@Value](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html)

```
@Value("${level.user}")
private String levelUser;

@Value("${user.update}")
private String userUpdate;
```

If it is xml driven then

```
<bean id="" class="some.myController">
    <property name="levelUser" value="${level.user}" />
    <property name="userUpdate" value="${user.update}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: how is your controller bean creaetd